# Are turing machines & equivalents with infinite sized random programs still turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, randomized-algorithms, randomness, probabilistic-algorithms

Are turing machines with an infinite program tape that is completely random, or another example is a Game of Life simulation on an infinite randomly initialized grid, still turing machines, so to speak?

edit: if this is the wrong place to ask this(?) remove it

Comment: This is the correct place to ask this, but you might want to be a bit more focused and formal about the specific question you want. Currently it borders being opinion-based, since it is not really well-defined what "equivalent to TM with infinite sized random memory" means. I took the interpretation of the question to ask only about TMs.

Answer (score 1):

They are still turing complete. Here is some intuition for why:

You can manually "clear", say, the first $100$ positions by replacing them with a blank. Then, we can "split" the tape into two parts by writing a special character $\#$, for which the first half are all of the tape contents before the first occurrence of $\#$ and the rest of the tape is everything else.

We can now consider the first part of the tape to be a "cleaned out" tape, like a usual TM would have. When we run out of space, we move $\#$ a few cells forward (any constant number you really want) and set the memory it the area it was before to $\sqcup$ (effectively allocating a constant extra memory and then clearing the contents out).